# How to apply different styles for the column headers in an Infragistics UltraWinGrid

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

We are using the Infragistics UltraWinGrid version 11.1.
We want to assign different styles (actually a different gradient) for some of the column headers in the same grid.
I have already tried things like
- defining 2 styles in the isl file and assigning them via StyleResourceName
- setting UseOsThemes to DefaultableBoolean.False
- setting column.Header.Appearance.ThemedElementAlpha to Alpha.Transparent
but to no avail.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have some tips here that might help you get to the property you are interested in changing, but I don't work with the Infragistics control set at this point, so I don't have a specific answer.  http://www.keithholloway.net/blog/infragistics-winform-ultragrid-quick-reference-guide/